# How to add computed value to the field?

Tags: magento-1.9, fieldsets

How to add computed value into the field:

```
        $fieldset->addField(
        'percentage',
        'text',
        array(
            'label'  => Mage::helper('edpa_adpan')->__('Drop/Rise %'),
            'name'   => 'percentage',
            'value'  => .....,
  //the function which calculate the difference between two fields is working in Grid perfectly, just don't know how to add this computed value to the field

        )
    );
```

Comment: By any chance, you have somewhere below your form definition something like this `$form->setValues(....)` ?

Comment: eeee nope I don't have anything like setValues ;(